# Switch between multiple views in Matlab GUI

Tags: user-interface, matlab

I'm working on a Matlab GUI application that has multiple "views". It behaves sort of like a Setup Wizard. When user finishes entering data in this "view", he click `Next` bottom. Then a different set of UI elements show up. The set of UI elements might be different, depending on what the user just entered.

I could draw all UI elements in one "view" and control them with visibility, but this is going to be a mess.

What is the best way to deal with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create separate GUIs (figures) for each step of the process, and pass information between them as needed. Alternatively, you could use one of the tab panel scripts available on Matlab file exchange (see [Tab Panel](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4780) for one example, others can be found via search).